# Oracle SQL Developer not displaying chinese characters properly?

Tags: sql, database, oracle, encoding, oracle-sqldeveloper

I've been playing with NCHAR datatype for a little in oracle database. I created a table with column NCHAR(50) and then tried to inserted some chinese characters however when I pasted the characters SQL developer is not able to display it properly then when inserted on the column its not able to display it properly as well. The encoding in Environment -> Encoding is set to UTF-8 then NLS_CHARACTERSET and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET are set to AL32UTF8 and AL16UTF16 respectively. How come its still not printing properly?

[image: Screenshot of result]

I updated the encoding from Cp1252 before to UTF-8 and the NLS_CHARACTERSET and NLS_NCHAR_CHARACTERSET are already set to unicode then restarted the sql developer but still same thing.

Comment: What do you mean "I updated the encoding"?  CP1252 isn't a valid database character set-- do you mean WE8MSWIN1252?  Did you use the Database Migration Assistant for Unicode (DMU) or did you use one of the unsupported methods floating around on the internet?

Comment: Yes updated the encoding value its located in Preferences -> Environment -> Encoding. Cp1252 is a valid character set i believe its similar to the one you mentioned. I didnt use DMU im not doing anything like that, im just curious why the behaviour is like this. if the SQL developer editor's encoding is set to UTF it should be able to print the characters properly as well as in result set when the table is queried?

Comment: I just created a simple table with 1 column with NCHAR datatype, im not doing anything serious just experimenting on this NCHAR

Comment: I assume you did everything correct, just the font does not support Chinese characters. Try a different font.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you're using an editor display font that supports Chinese characters, here's your test -

[image]

Oracle SQL Developer is a Java swing application, everything is Unicode by definition.

Comment: Yup this is the reason, I was using consolas font it doesnt support chinese characters. Thank you for this